# should i need to add NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key info.plist. am not using any library related to image

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

should i need to add NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key info.plist . i am not using any library  related to image.

then why i get this mail

**This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.**

Comment: May be this issue because of the third party library you have used

Comment: have you fix it ?

Answer (score 16):

may be you are using somewhere `UIImagePicker` or in somewhere in library so you are accessing user's Images that's why and it is count as accessing user's private data.

if you are not using any framework still you have to add a key to avoid any rejection chance from apple.

Just add this key safe side

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Photo Library Access Warning</string>
```

Comment: In XCode, I searched `UIImagePicker` and found a library that was using it. Found alternative to library and no more and fixed issue.

Comment: @levibostian i m having the same issue..after some research i found this hope it will help..

Comment: Same issue. No libraries, using any photo related stuff. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ArtemZaytsev have u added this key ? and tried ? also check permissions that you are asking for.

Comment: Yeah, in spite of i didn't found any photo library usage, adding a key fixed the problem with apple and app was accepted for testing. Thanks!